# Pyspark - grouping the description column details in an array

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the below sample dataset, I have two groups 'A' and 'B'. The 'Description' column contains the details associated with group 'A' and whenever an instance of group 'B' occurs, I need to add the description details associated with prior instances of group 'A' in an array and put it against group 'B' in a new dataset.

Sample dataset:

| Description | Group |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | A |
| PQR | A |
|  | B |
| DEF | A |
| HIJ | A |
| KLM | A |
| NOP | A |
|  | B |

Expected Output:

| Group | Description |
| --- | --- |
| B | [XYZ,PQR] |
| B | [DEF,HIJ,KLM,NOP] |

Comment: And which column determines the order of rows?

Comment: By order of rows if you mean a primary key column then a sequence number starting from 1 can be added.

Comment: Fix your question then: add order by column which will determine the same order as in your dataset and can be used in analytics functions please. Without it, it is not possible to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have column `id`, which determines the order of rows.

Calculate group number as running count of group B occurrences, then aggregate using collect_list, see the code. It is scala, but the same spark.sql will work in pyspark:

```
println("Initial data:")
val df1 = Seq(
(1, "XYZ",  "A"),
(2, "PQR" , "A"),
(3,null, "B"   ),
(4,"DEF",   "A"),
(5,"HIJ",   "A"),
(6,"KLM",   "A"),
(7,"NOP",   "A"),
(8,null,    "B"    )
).toDF("Id","Description", "Group")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df1.show(100, false)

println("Result:")
spark.sql(""" 
select 'B' Group, collect_list(Description) Description
from
(
select id, Description, Group, 
       --calculate group number
       count(case when Group='B' then 1 else null end) over(order by id) as grp_num
from df1
) s
group by grp_num
having size(collect_list(Description))>0
order by grp_num

""").show(100, false)
```

Initial data:

```
+---+-----------+-----+
|Id |Description|Group|
+---+-----------+-----+
|1  |XYZ        |A    |
|2  |PQR        |A    |
|3  |null       |B    |
|4  |DEF        |A    |
|5  |HIJ        |A    |
|6  |KLM        |A    |
|7  |NOP        |A    |
|8  |null       |B    |
+---+-----------+-----+
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|Group|Description         |
+-----+--------------------+
|B    |[XYZ, PQR]          |
|B    |[DEF, HIJ, KLM, NOP]|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works for me :)